# If the energy of an aircraft is the sum of its Kinetic Energ and Potential Energy, what does reducing the aircraft's weight do?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

As per the title, if the energy of an aircraft is the sum of its Kinetic Energy,$=\frac12 mv^2$, and Potential Energy,$=mgh$, Does reducing its mass increase its energy?

I am trying to write an explanation why using a lighter material on aircraft is a good idea, and one reason is to reduce it's overall weight - but what effect of reducing it's weight does it have? I can't get it in to words which make sense. It will obviously use less fuel etc, but why - which formulas come in to play?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "I am trying to write an explanation why using a lighter material on aircraft is a good idea" -- if you don't understand it, why do you believe it? And the answer is already contained in the formulas you cited. And I should add, the main thing is that we can't recover the energy spent.

Comment: *"Does reducing its mass increase its energy?"* Look at your own formlas: obviously **NOT**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to write an explanation why using a lighter material on aircraft is a good idea, and one reason is to reduce it's overall weight - but what effect of reducing it's weight does it have?

In order to get an airplane from stationary on the tarmac to cruising speed $v$ and cruising altitude $h$ we have to spend energy:

$$T=\frac12 mv^2+mgh$$

This is even without taking into account the energy losses due to *air drag*.

To achieve this, thrust $\vec{F}$ is applied by the engines, causing acceleration $\vec{a}$:

$$\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$$

This force perfoms work $W$ on the plane ($\vec{r}$ is the position vector):

$$W=\int_{\mathrm{trajectory}}\vec{F}\mathrm{d}\vec{r}=\int_{\mathrm{trajectory}}m\vec{a}\mathrm{d}\vec{r}$$

Assuming $m$ is constant:

$$W=m\int_{\mathrm{trajectory}}\vec{a}\mathrm{d}\vec{r}$$

(Note again that work done against drag forces is not accounted for here. These condiderably increase the amount of work needed)

So this amount $W$ is proportional to the mass $m$ and is of course directly **proportional to the amount of fuel used**.

Once the plane has achieved cruising speed and altitude, only work done against the air drag forces are needed to maintain constant flight conditions:

$$W=\int_{\mathrm{trajectory}}\vec{F}_{drag}\mathrm{d}\vec{r}$$

$\vec{F}_{drag}$ is usually modelled as:

$$F_{drag}=\frac{1}{2} \rho C_D A v^2,$$

where $A$ is the cross section of the plane. So while $F_{drag}$ does not depend directly on mass, it does depend on plane size.

Comment: +1 for answering it in a physics fashion, I assumed the OP would be sort of familiar with these concepts, so hopefully your (very fast) answer strikes a chord, ahem.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to write an explanation why using a lighter material on aircraft is a good idea, and one reason is to reduce it's overall weight - but what effect of reducing it's weight does it have?

In all cases, the lighter the weight of the aircraft, the more weight, passengers whatever, you can carry for a given power setting on the enginedge.

However, don't just think physics in this case, think money........

If you are Ryanair, and you have 400 aircraft, all of which are as light as possible, you save money in three ways:

1. You don't use as much fuel.
2. You don't use as much fuel carrying the fuel mentioned above.
3. You save on landing fees, which airports charge usually per ton of aircraft thumping down and chewing up their runways.

Every extra kilo will add up very quickly in monetary terms.

If you are dealing with Cessna sized aircraft, it's mainly fuel saving and extra carrying capacity.

There are other reasons,  but these are the main fuel related saving ones.

Answer (score 0):

Yes reducing an aircrafts weight reduces the total energy. The lift on aircraft depends on the surface  area of  the planes wing and the properties of the fluid surrounding it as well as the velocity of the plane. so L=coefficient of fluid *((density of fluid *velocity^2) /2)*surface area of wing.  But remember the aircraft needs to stay In equilibrium so the lift has to balance the weight of the aircraft mg which means that an  aircraft that has less mass can balance out the weight vector with less velocity.